# Azure Data Factory Assembly Auto-generated header code

Tags: .net-assembly, azure-data-factory

I've the code in a proyect visual studio (.sln) but i not see the code assembly, i see only U-SQL code

The question is, how did generate this assemly?, 
because i deleted it and the compilater the function not found

```
// Auto-generated header code

CREATE ASSEMBLY [__codeBehind_nfnmcapn.2b0] FROM 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

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [__codeBehind_nfnmcapn.2b0];

// Auto-generated header code ended

// User script

CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM @"/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM @"/bin/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";

// B. REFERENCE ASSEMBLY: Load assemblies for compile time and execution.
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

// FROM HERE MY CODE U-SQL
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.  Always post code as text.  I have downvotes your question until you fix that.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post